# Openstack Heat install [ERROR: All heat engines are down.]

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I have successfully installed OpenStack Victoria on Ubuntu 20.04. After installing heat using this guide https://docs.openstack.org/heat/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html and verifying using same guide with

#openstack orchestration service list

I get

```
ERROR: All heat engines are down.
```

These are the logs

````
2021-05-17 12:46:19.045 277441 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/common/pluginutils.py", line 23, in log_fail_msg
2021-05-17 12:46:19.045 277441 ERROR heat-engine     {'module_name': entrypoint.module,
2021-05-17 12:46:19.045 277441 ERROR heat-engine AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module'
2021-05-17 12:46:19.045 277441 ERROR heat-engine
2021-05-17 12:46:22.500 277447 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading KWallet
2021-05-17 12:46:22.507 277447 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading SecretService
2021-05-17 12:46:22.509 277447 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading Windows
2021-05-17 12:46:22.510 277447 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading chainer
2021-05-17 12:46:22.511 277447 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading macOS
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 CRITICAL heat-engine [-] Unhandled error: AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module'
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 221, in _load_plugins
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     ext = self._load_one_plugin(ep,
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/enabled.py", line 77, in _load_one_plugin
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     ext = super(EnabledExtensionManager, self)._load_one_plugin(
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 255, in _load_one_plugin
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     plugin = ep.load()
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     module = import_module(match.group('module'))
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/clients/os/zun.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     from zunclient import client as zun_client
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zunclient'
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/bin/heat-engine", line 10, in <module>
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     sys.exit(main())
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/cmd/engine.py", line 90, in main
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     launcher = launch_engine()
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/cmd/engine.py", line 79, in launch_engine
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     srv = engine.EngineService(CONF.host, rpc_api.ENGINE_TOPIC)
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/service.py", line 359, in __init__
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     resources.initialise()
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resources/__init__.py", line 65, in initialise
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     clients.initialise()
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/clients/__init__.py", line 125, in initialise
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     _mgr = enabled.EnabledExtensionManager(
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/enabled.py", line 65, in __init__
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     super(EnabledExtensionManager, self).__init__(
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 133, in __init__
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     extensions = self._load_plugins(invoke_on_load,
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 233, in _load_plugins
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     self._on_load_failure_callback(self, ep, err)
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/common/pluginutils.py", line 23, in log_fail_msg
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine     {'module_name': entrypoint.module,
2021-05-17 12:46:22.626 277447 ERROR heat-engine AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module' 



root@controller:~# tail -f /var/log/heat/heat-api.log
2021-05-17 09:41:21.586 243980 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] (243980) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8004
2021-05-17 09:41:21.587 243958 INFO heat.common.wsgi [-] Started child 243981
2021-05-17 09:41:21.591 243981 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] (243981) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8004
2021-05-17 09:41:21.591 243958 INFO heat.common.wsgi [-] Started child 243982
2021-05-17 09:41:21.597 243982 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] (243982) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8004
2021-05-17 09:41:21.598 243958 INFO heat.common.wsgi [-] Started child 243983
2021-05-17 09:41:21.602 243983 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] (243983) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8004
2021-05-17 09:41:41.116 243976 INFO heat.common.wsgi [req-2c13678b-8127-4aac-86ee-10ffb9af8a8c admin admin - default default] Processing request: GET /v1/219c35c909e74a73b538c4875d826825/services
2021-05-17 09:42:41.168 243976 ERROR heat.common.wsgi [req-2c13678b-8127-4aac-86ee-10ffb9af8a8c admin admin - default default] Returning 503 to user: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.: webob.exc.HTTPServiceUnavailable: All heat engines are down.
2021-05-17 09:42:41.176 243976 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-2c13678b-8127-4aac-86ee-10ffb9af8a8c admin admin - default default] 127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2021 09:42:41] "GET /v1/219c35c909e74a73b538c4875d826825/services HTTP/1.1" 503 455 61.362854```
````

Please if you need anything else let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing this missing package the issue was finally resolved

pip install python-zunclient

Hope this helps someone!